# Appending values to a Numpy array while iterating over that same array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D Numpy array containing instances of a class. I need to iterate over that array, and use each object to decide whether to append a new instance to that same array. This process will run until the loop reaches the last object in the array, and decides not to append a new instance.

At first I used a list instead of an array and a for loop:

```
for obj in objList:

    # Use 'obj' to make some calculations for the condition

    if condition:
        objList.append(newObject)
```

But it needs to be an array for other purposes in the full script, and the for loop method doesn't work with an array, so I came up with the below code. It works, but I wanted to see if there is a better way to handle this?

```
i = 0
while True:

    try:
        obj = objArray[i]
        i += 1
    except IndexError:
        break

    # Use 'obj' to make some calculations for the condition

    if condition:
        objArray = np.append(objArray, newObject)
```

Comment: `np.append()` is inefficient here since it creates a copy of the whole array in order to add each extra element. It is better to append to a list, and only when the loop finishes convert the list to an array. Also, won't the code you wrote run forever? If an object satisfies the condition, you append it to the array. Then while iterating you will encounter this object again, and since it satisfies the condition you will append it again and so on.

Comment: @bb1 That makes sense, and the list method is cleaner as well so I will go with that. The code doesn't run forever, it is "filling a circle with smaller circles" so eventually when there is no more room in the big circle the condition can no longer be met... Hope that makes sense, it's hard to explain in text.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just use a temporary variable.

```
temp = np.array([])

i = 0
while True:

    try:
        obj = objArray[i]
        i += 1
    except IndexError:
        break

    # Use 'obj' to make some calculations for the condition

    if condition:
        temp = np.append(temp, newObject)

objArray = temp
```